# Entity Framework type case generic in predicate

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am working on updating to a more manageable repository pattern in my MVC 4 project that uses Entity Framework code first. I've integrated a generic base repository class that will do basic CRUD operations so I don't have to implement these in each repository I create. I have ran into an issue where my All method needs to filter there query by a deleted flag if the entity is a type of TrackableEntity. Since the Entity is generic in the base repository I am attempting to cast is to a type of TrackableEntity in the where which just results in the following error message.

> The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'NameSpace.Models.ClientFormField' and a check of type 'NameSpace.Models.TrackableEntity' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.

This error makes complete since and I understand why the code I have is not working but I am trying to find a way to filter out deleted items without having to override this method in all of my repositories. The code I have for my All method is below.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> All()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(TrackableEntity)))
        return dbSet.Where(e => !(e as TrackableEntity).IsDeleted).ToList();

    return dbSet.ToList();
}
```

I know that I can do the following

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> All(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    if (predicate != null)
        return dbSet.Where(predicate).IsDeleted).ToList();

    return dbSet.ToList();
}
```

And then add this to all of my repositories

```
public override IEnumerable<CaseType> All(Expression<Func<CaseType,bool>> predicate = null)
{
    if (predicate == null)
        predicate = e => !e.IsDeleted;
    return base.All(predicate);
}
```

The problem I have with this is that I am duplicating code, this is basically a copy and paste into all of my repositories which defeats the purpose of changing to this new repository pattern. I made the switch to end duplicated code in my repositories.

Here is an example of one of my entities.

```
public class CaseType : TrackableEntity, IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool InUse { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid { get { return !this.Validate(null).Any(); } }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            yield return new ValidationResult("Case Type name cannot be blank", new[] { "Name" });

        //Finish Validation Rules
    }
}
```

And the TrackableEntity

```
public abstract class TrackableEntity
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `dbSet.OfType<TrackableEntity>().Where(e => !e.IsDeleted).ToList()`?

Comment: I get "'NameSpace.Models.TrackableEntity' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types." When trying return dbSet.OfType<TrackableEntity>().Where(e => !e.IsDeleted).ToList() as IEnumerable<T>; I had to cast again to make the return type happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a solution working that I am happy with. I ended up making 2 generic repositories. One that is the base repository which deals with all of the calls to the database for my BaseEntity which all entities inherit from. Then I made my 2nd generic repo which is inherits BaesEntity and overrides a few methods to handle the needs of my TrackableEntities. In the end this does what I want by handling the filtering of soft deleted items from within the repo and also gives me more flexibility with the TrackableEntity.

BaseRepository -

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IAppDb _db;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(IAppDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _dbSet = Lwdb.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IAppDb Lwdb
    {
        get { return _db; }
    }

    #region IBaseRepository<T> Members

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        _db.Commit();
        return entity;
    }

    public virtual bool Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return _dbSet.Any(expression);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        _db.Commit();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> All()
    {
        return _dbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual T Update(T entity, bool attachOnly = false)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _db.SetModified(entity);
        if (!attachOnly) _db.Commit();
        return entity;
    }

    #endregion

    protected User GetCurrentUser()
    {
        return
            _db.Set<User>().Find(HttpContext.Current != null ? ((User) HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]).Id : 1);
    }
```

BaseTrackableEntityRepository -

```
public class BaseTrackableEntityRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T>, IBaseTrackableEntityRepository<T>
    where T : TrackableEntity
{
    private readonly IAppDb _db;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _teDB;

    public BaseTrackableEntityRepository(IAppDb db)
        : base(db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _teDB = _db.Set<T>();
    }

    #region IBaseTrackableEntityRepository<T> Members

    public virtual T SetDeleteFlag(int id)
    {
        var entity = _teDB.Find(id);
        if (entity == null) return null; //throw exception
        entity.IsDeleted = true;
        entity.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        entity.ModifiedBy = GetCurrentUser();
        return Update(entity);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> All()
    {
        return _teDB.Where(e => !e.IsDeleted).ToList();
    }

    public override T Add(T entity)
    {
        var curUser = GetCurrentUser();
        entity.CreatedBy = curUser;
        entity.ModifiedBy = curUser;
        entity.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        entity.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        entity.Active = true;
        entity.IsDeleted = false;
        _teDB.Add(entity);
        _db.Commit();
        return entity;
    }

    public override T Update(T entity, bool attachOnly = false)
    {
        InsertTeData(ref entity);
        entity.ModifiedBy = GetCurrentUser();
        entity.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        _teDB.Attach(entity);
        _db.SetModified(entity);
        if (!attachOnly) _db.Commit();
        return entity;
    }

    public virtual T SetStatus(int id, bool status)
    {
        var entity = _teDB.Find(id);
        if (entity == null) return null;
        entity.Active = status;
        return Update(entity);
    }

    #endregion

    private void InsertTeData(ref T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null || entity == null) return;
        var dbEntity = GetById(entity.Id);
        if (dbEntity == null) return;
        _db.Detach(dbEntity);
        entity.CreatedBy = dbEntity.CreatedBy;
        entity.DateCreated = dbEntity.DateCreated;
        entity.ModifiedBy = dbEntity.ModifiedBy;
        entity.DateModified = dbEntity.DateModified;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, first thanks for pointing the problem and especially (of course) the solution.

I have the same error as you but with a different situation.